# LifecycleObserver is not working

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components

Observer methods are not being called. I tested `ViewPagerCycler` as in old school ways and working perfect. Thanks for help.

```
public final class ViewPagerCycler implements LifecycleObserver {

    private static final int PERIOD = 3000;

    private Timer mTimer;
    private TimerTask mTask;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    public ViewPagerCycler(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mPager = pager;
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) public void start() {
        int count = mPager
            .getAdapter()
            .getCount();

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override public void run() {
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        mPager.setCurrentItem((mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1) % count, true);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        mTimer.schedule(mTask, PERIOD, PERIOD);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) public void stop() {
        mTask.cancel();
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer.purge();
    }
}
```

Activity is just summarized. I didn't add `findViewById`s.

```
public class SummariziedActivity extends Activity implements LifecycleOwner {
   private final LifecycleRegistry mRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

   @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       mRegistry.addObserver(new ViewPagerCycler(mPager));
   }
}
```

In the `build.gradle`:

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha2"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha2"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha2"
```

Comment: Can you post your activity?

Comment: @azizbekian done. Thanks for help

Comment: I have same problem but any answer do not works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of extending ordinary `Activity`, you should extend from `LifecycleActivity`.

Otherwise, you can refer to ["Implementing LifecycleOwner in custom activities and fragments"](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html#implementing-lco):

> Any custom fragment or activity can be turned into a **LifecycleOwner** by implementing the built-in **LifecycleRegistryOwner** interface (instead of extending **LifecycleFragment** or **LifecycleActivity**).

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LifecycleRegistryOwner {
        LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

        @Override
        public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
            return lifecycleRegistry;
        }
    }
```

> If you have a custom class that you would like to make a **LifecycleOwner**, you can use the **LifecycleRegistry** class, but you will need to forward events into that class. This forwarding is done automatically for fragments and activities if they implement the **LifecycleRegistryOwner** interface.

Comment: Actually i am using Custom Activity, Reference : Implementing LifecycleOwner in custom activities and fragments (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html)

Comment: Yes, but you haven't correctly applied suggestions specified [in docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html#implementing-lco).

Comment: I agree here, @EmreAktürk you should implement `LifecycleRegistryOwner`, otherwise you have to forward lifecycle events by yourself to your observer.

Comment: Oh didnt noticed that I just implemented wrong Interface. Therefore there was no exception. I will accept answer after testing in a hour. :)

Comment: I exactly implement LifecycleOwner Actvity but any lifecycle events not triggers.

Comment: Dec 2018 it seems LifecycleRegistryOwner is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like implementing `LifecycleRegistryOwner` is not enough.

I came across the same problem in `1.0.0-alpha1` and I actually needed to forward lifecycle events to the `Lifecycle` instance myself in order to make it work. This is because either the documentation does not conform to the implementation, or this is a bug in the library.

I only used `onStart()` and `onStop()` in my `Observers`, so I forwarded these lifecycle events to the `Lifecycle`.

```
abstract class LifecyclePreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment(), LifecycleRegistryOwner {

    private val mLifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    override fun getLifecycle() = mLifecycleRegistry

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem is being tracked in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62160522).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are extending the platform default `Activity` class instead of the support library's `FragmentActivity`.

This is what a Google engineer states in this [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62160522):

> Yeah, we don't currently target platform Activity / Fragments.
>
> I'm keeping this open, but we are not looking to fix this in the
>   nearest future.
>
> PS for people who uses platform fragments: please consider the usage
>   support library fragments. When you use platform fragments, it means
>   that your code depends on multiple years old implementation of
>   fragments, which is shipped with a device. Those implementation are
>   usually very old and has a lot of bugs that are already fixed in
>   support library.

You can see in the lifecycle implementation that the lifecycle tracking is only enabled for `FragmentActivity`, for instance in the following extract of `LifecycleDispatcher.java`:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(mFragmentCallback, true);
        }
        ReportFragment.injectIfNeededIn(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            markState((FragmentActivity) activity, CREATED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            markState((FragmentActivity) activity, CREATED);
        }
    }
```

For more info on how lifecycle events dispatch is implemented you can see this other answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45701439/2510655

Comment: However, I'm using `AppCompatActivity` which extends `FragmentActivity`, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Support Library 26.1.0, if your Activity/Fragment extends from its classes, you get the lifecycle callbacks for free.

This is why you can do something like that:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc

```
lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        Log.d("AppLog", "onDestroy")
    }
```

Comment: Android Studio Bumblebee says: "'OnLifecycleEvent' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java"

Comment: @rwst Updated answer with new, non deprecated solution

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle.Observer(new observer);

to

getLifecycle().Observer(new observer);

100% working