# When does a LifecycleRegistry instance start listening to LifecycleOwner's lifecycle changes?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-lifecycle

I've started learning architecture components, but can't find one thing.

[LifecycleFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleFragment.html) just creates a new [LifecycleRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry.html) object, which does not start observing the fragment's lifecycle.

I guess the LifecycleRegistry object starts listening to the fragment's lifecycle when we, for example, put it into [LiveData.observe()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E)) as first param, but I haven't found any proof of this in source code.

Question: When and how does a [LifecycleRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry.html) object start to observe a fragment's lifecycle and refresh `LifecycleRegistry.mState`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `ContentProvider` called `LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider` that is merged into the app's `AndroidManifest.xml`. In its `onCreate` method it initializes a singleton called `LifecycleDispatcher`, which is responsible for updating all `LifecycleRegistry` instances.

`LifecycleDispatcher` uses the [Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) method that has been around since API 14 to get notified when a new activity is created. At this point it injects an instance of `ReportFragment` into the activity. The `ReportFragment` uses the `Fragment` lifecycle callbacks to update the activity's `LifecycleRegistry` if necessary, like this:

```
@Override
public void onStop() { // Showing onStop as example
    super.onStop();
    dispatch(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP);
}

private void dispatch(Lifecycle.Event event) {
    if (getActivity() instanceof LifecycleRegistryOwner) {
        ((LifecycleRegistryOwner) getActivity()).getLifecycle().handleLifecycleEvent(event);
    }
}
```

If the new activity is a `FragmentActivity`, the `LifecycleDispatcher` calls [FragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks,%20boolean)) to get notified of the activity's fragments lifecycle events. It relays the `onFragmentCreated`, `onFragmentStarted` and `onFragmentResumed` callbacks to the `LifecycleRegistry` in case the fragment is a `LifecycleRegistryOwner`, in the same way as before.

The `onFragmentPaused`, `onFragmentStopped`, and `onFragmentDestroyed` callbacks are called after the corresponding callbacks are called on the fragment, but the `LifecycleObserver` callbacks must be called before. So whenever a fragment is created, the `LifecycleDispatcher` injects an instance of `LifecycleDispatcher.DestructionReportFragment` into it. The `DestructionReportFragment`'s lifecycle callbacks are used to update the registry for the pause, stop and destroy events.

I can't link to the code because it hasn't been released yet, but you can browse it in Android Studio after you add the library to your project.

Answer (score 4):

As Mordag said, as of now, both the LifecycleActivity and LifecycleFragment are not yet implemented. In their documentation Google says:

> Any custom fragment or activity can be turned into a LifecycleOwner by implementing the built-in LifecycleRegistryOwner interface (instead of extending LifecycleFragment or LifecycleActivity).

However, that is only half the story, because naturally you are using these Lifecycle Aware components to be able to react to your Activity/Fragment lifecycles and with their code snippet it just doesn't work, because initialising a LifecycleRegistry with the Activity/Fragment like this

```
LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
```

only gets you a Lifecycle in the INITIALIZED state.

So, long story short, in order for this to work right now (BEFORE their 1.0-release) it is you who have to implement the Lifecycle of the Activity/Fragment that implements the LifecycleRegistry. So, for each callback of the Activity/Fragment you need to do this:

```
public class ScoreMasterFragment extends Fragment
                                 implements LifecycleRegistryOwner {


    private LifecycleRegistry lifecycle;

    @Override
    public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
        return lifecycle;
    }

    public ScoreMasterFragment(){
         lifecycle = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //more code here
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //more code here
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //more code here
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //more code here
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //more code here
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //more code here
        _lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY);
    }
```

This will likely be in the code of the future LifecycleActivity and LifecycleFragment, but until then, if you put your Activities/Fragments observing some LifecycleAware object (like LiveData) you will have to do this.

In the case of LiveData, because it will not notify its observers unless they are at least in the STARTED state and in other cases because other LifecycleAware components cannot react to a Lifecycle if its only state is INITIALIZED.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but no, I don't need do all of this callbacks, it work's right now. You only need to define LifecycleRegistry and implement LifecycleOwner

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question then. But what I wrote is basically defining a LifecycleRegistry which I believe you'll need when observing LiveData. Wasn't that you were looking for?

Comment: Carlos, im looking for how activity or fragment send information about change lifecycle to LifecycleRegistry object

Comment: And could you please maybe edit your question with some code to make it a bit clearer on what you are trying to do? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The LifecycleFragment and LifecycleActivity are currently not fully implemented. Those classes will be implemented when the lib is reaching 1.0-release. Currently you can use those LifecycleRegistry to observe LiveData objects. Those objects are based on a future result which could e.g. be an object from your database.

The official documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html

Official statement regarding the two classes you mentioned:

> Lifecycle Fragment and ActivityCompat in the Support Library do not
>   yet implement LifecycleOwner interface. They will when Architecture
>   Components reaches 1.0.0 version.

Answer (score -1):

LifecycleActivity ,LifecycleFragment and LifecycleRegistryOwner interface  are  deprecated  in API level 1.0.0.  Use android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity and   android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of it.
Official documentation here [LifecycleActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleActivity.html) [LifeCycleFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleFragment.html)