# How to observe a collection from android foreground (vpn)service

Tags: android, observable, foreground-service, android-vpn-service

I have a singleton class with the "block/allow logic" for my VPN tunnel. Packets sent into the tunnel are not emitted, applications are allowed to bypass based on an allowance list, therefore it can behave as a simple implementation of a firewall.

What I want to do is, when I change the `Set<String>` of blocked application packagenames, I would like the service thread to run `vpnservice.builder.establish()` again, using this blocked application set.

An obvious choice for this - in case an "ordinary" foreground service if the service `extends LifecycleService`, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708202/observe-livedata-from-foreground-service). However, my service has to extend `android.net.VpnService`, which does **not** implement `LifecycleOwner`. A possible implementation (with some modifications needed) [is shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823964/3169248).

My questions are:

1. Is there a better, cleaner, more elegant way for my VPN service to observe changes in my blockedPackageName Collection, in my singleton class?
2. If there is not another way, will implementing `LifecycleOwner` work in the way I expect it (how I described it, basically)?
3. If(2), is it enough to add `lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.XXXX);` in my service's onCreate and onDestroy methods (see below)? Do these do anything apart from preventing memory leaks?

   ```
   //MyVpnService class
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       Log.i(TAG, "Destroyed.");
       stopVpn();
       //what is the purpose of this line for my goals? 
       lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY);
   }
   ```

P.S.: I read the official documentation with regards to Lifecycle components, but I could not find enough code examples for my cases to make the matter more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I find was to send a broadcast with a custom intent from the singleton class, and signing up a broadcast receiver for this intent in the vpnservice class on start.
For sending a broadcast from any class, you need context - lucky for me, I already needed context in my singleton, for which `context.getApplicationContext()` works fine without leaking.